# Tableau integration with python

Tags: python, tableau-api

Is there any reliable way to parse the inbuilt query statements in a tableau workbook, apart from xml parsing? Since my main intention is to analyze what the tableau is doing, I don't think TabPy is what I need.

Comment: What in-built queries are you referring to? Assuming custom SQL is not in use, then all queries are generated by Tableau and logged at run-time when the workbook is opened - they are not present in the workbook XML itself

Comment: I ought to have been clearer in my question. My requirement is to parse the custom SQL queries (and initial one-time queries, if any) present in a Tableau workbook file. Currently, I am parsing the workbook as an XML file, with some level of hardcoding to look for the connection and the relation tags in the document tree. I wanted to know if there is a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it does not appear to be possible to read custom SQL,  the [Tableau Document API on GitHub](https://github.com/tableau/document-api-python/blob/master/README.md) does allow for programmatic checking of datasources and initial SQL